# X high CPU when using Java applications

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, performance, java

Only recently, my Freemind program has become extremely sluggish and unresponsive (big lag) when moving my mind map around. I use Arch Linux with xfce4. Freemind is made with Java. If I move the mind map around, the X process shoots to 20% CPU, doesn't seem a lot but something between X and Java programs are really bringing their performance down.

I can barely use Freemind now. Freeplane is also affected.

I noticed if I keep the Freemind window really small, it's responsive. If I maximise it, everything slows down within the application. Adding new notes, or move the map around, shoots X to a high CPU and there is a 5+ second lag in anything I do in the app.

Is there anything I can do to improve performance? It's only started recently, everything is up-to-date.

Comment: Are you using IcedTea or Oracle's Java? Try the other one to see if it solves it.

Comment: IcedTea. Worried about Oracle in Arch Linux. I believe it's discontinued and an old version now?

Comment: I'm not using Arch, but you can download [Java from Oracle's website](http://java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp?locale=en).

Comment: Thank you, the jre package from the Arch AUR fixed the problem (in other words, replacing openjre with Oracle's one).

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem has returned. It seemed OK at first, but the next day the same exact problem returned. The X process is on high CPU if I move the Freeplane Mind Map around - and the whole program becomes unresponsive. I reverted to openjre again. Still hoping to identify the cause :(

Comment: Problem is solved for me today after updating my system. The main updates being a Linux kernal and Intel x86 video drivers.